# Android: How to remove transparant overlay in ICS actionbar-tabbar

Tags: android, background, overlay, tabbar, android-actionbar

How can I remove the transparent light colored overlay or background in the tabbar that comes with the actionbar.
I using the actionbar with navigation method set to tabs. The tabs I add here are styled with a "none" background. The tabbar has a background set via XML but turns out way lighter than the original.

Comment: Noticed this same issue. Causes a problem when you try to use the same color in the action bar and in the body of the app, the colors won't match because the action bar color is slightly lighter.